# Detect Internet Explorer 6 or below in jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I'm new to jquery and was wondering: is a simple way to detect whether a browser is Internet Explorer 6 or below?

Comment: $.browser has been deprecated. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944169/detecting-ie-using-jquery more details

Answer (score 102, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0") alert("Im the annoying IE6");
```

**Update**

Please note that [$.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) is [removed from jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)

If you still need to use $.browser in jQuery 1.9 (or other deprecated functions), try jQuery-migrate (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/ - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js)

Comment: For detecting a specific version of Internet Explorer only, Aamir's approach is almost perfect in my opinion.

However, I think you should test the value of $.browser.version as an integer, not as a string.  Then you can do more interesting things, like apply bindings on document load to fix common bugs across IE7 and IE6 simultaneously (for example).

But I write only from the explicit point of view that I only care about 1) Microsoft Internet Explorer, and 2) what version it is if detected.  Deprecated or not, querying $.browser and $.browser.version was the most direct approach for me.

Comment: Another way can be:
($.browser.msie && /6.0/.test(navigator.userAgent) )

Comment: ...until they get to IE version 16.0, or 8.6.0, etc.

Comment: Note: `jQuery.browser` is removed in 1.9. A plugin is needed.

Comment: If you still need to use $.browser in jQuery 1.9 (or other deprecated functions), also add a reference to jQuery-migrate (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js)

Answer (score 50):

You could also ask IE directly.

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var isRunningIE6OrBelow = true;
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 17):

jQuery checks for features, rather than "browsers". That said, you can use the [**jQuery.support**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support) method to detect what the users browser is capable of.

Deprecated Methods (Do not use)

- $.browser
- $.browser.version
- $.boxModel

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support will give you a summary of which features are supported by which browsers. Taking that data, you'll develop a couple conditional checks to determine if the browser being used is your target browser or not.

Comment: This is relevant if the user wants to detect that functionality, but there's no jQuery.support method to check for: "does the browser add hashes to the browser history" or the like, so it's more appropriate at that point to detect browser version instead of "does it support .cssFloat and .htmlSerialized?

Answer (score 8):

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 6) {
  alert("I'm not dead yet!"); 
}
```

-- update

Please not that [$.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) is [removed from jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)

Answer (score 6):

Very nice way to detect IE is:

```
if ('v'=='\v') {
   welcome to IE )) 
}
```

Unfortunately it can't recognize its version but it's not always nessecary.

Answer (score 5):

If `ActiveXObject` exists and `XMLHttpRequest` does not, it's IE6:

```
/* IE6 Check */
(!!window.ActiveXObject && !window.XMLHttpRequest) ? true : false;
```

In IE7, it would be:

```
(!!window.ActiveXObject && !!window.XMLHttpRequest) ? true: false;
```

**References**

- [JavaScriptKit: AJAX](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/ajax.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

> Also, another good point is that with JQuery, you are not supposed to worry about the version.

That doesn't help if you're using jquery to fix an IE6 css rendering bug though.

Answer (score 3):

I often check the version of a browser.  The .support method is great, but it doesn't really help when you need to hide selects when there's an overlay.  There is no "supports selects are windowed controls".  You just need to check the browser version, so I would say err towards the .support method where you can, and use the .browser where necessary.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. So many people shout the praises of `$.support`, but I've never *ever* found it useful. It is designed for internal- and plugin-use only, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Just to let people know
$.browser.msie && /6.0/.test(navigator.userAgent) 
is not reliable, I've come to this question looking for an answer to a problem with the JQuery bgiframe which breaks on my machine because I have 'Media Center PC 6.0' in my navigator.userAgent string.  I've now edited the source to use the $browser.version test.

Its silly of JQuery to deprecate these browser tests because ugly as they may be they are necessary to deal with the ugly state of the browser ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

i always used this solution

http://sinfinity.pl/blog/2012/02/12/detect-internet-explorer-and-browser-version-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser.version is how

**EDITED:  Corrected link from Douglas**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/#jQuery.browser.version

I mean, if you had the old version not the latest 1.3...

Also, another good point is that with JQuery, you are not supposed to worry about the version.  JQuery does feature testing and handles all that malarky for you.  Worrying about versions and platforms is pretty 1999

Comment: Companies still demand support for IE6 and you often have to do things specifically for it. I'm pretty baffled that .browser is removed, that's just stupid.

Comment: Alex, I'm with you on that. Off topic, I just happened to notice that you are the creator of SyntaxHighlighter. Nice work, I use it on my personal site.

Comment: Above link is broken, should be: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/#jQuery.browser.version

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
 jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val) {
  $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>")
            .appendTo(document.body);
});
```

if you need more info refer to this:

http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser

Answer (score 0):

> "While it is unlikely jQuery.browser
>   will be removed, every effort to use
>   jQuery.support and proper feature
>   detection should be made."

So I say go ahead and use it.  They have to maintain backwards-compatibility with scripts that still use the user-agent sniffing method.