# Detecting IE using jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser-detection

```
$(window).load(function () {
   if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0") {
     // do stuff
   }
});
```

Just realized that $.browser has been depreciated in 1.3. What is the new method for detecting IE, specially IE6.

Comment: `jQuery.browser` is not deprecated. Although it is no longer used by jQuery internally it's available to user scripts for the indefinite future: http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser

Comment: The documentation says "Deprecated in jQuery 1.3 (see `jQuery.support`) The version number of the rendering engine for the user's browser.".

Comment: *Feature detection* is much better than *browser sniffing*, what are you trying to achieve when your page is rendered by IE6?

Comment: We need to all make a pact as web developers to boycott IE until people stop using it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [jQuery documentation for `jQuery.browser`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser) shows the following warning.  (Emphasis is mine.)

> Because `$.browser` uses `navigator.userAgent` to determine the platform, **it is vulnerable to spoofing by the user or misrepresentation by the browser** itself. **It is always best to avoid browser-specific code entirely** where possible. Instead of relying on `$.browser` it's better to use libraries like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

The documentation page also says:

> This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.

Even [`jQuery.support`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.support), which was suggested from the old documentation has the following warning. (Emphasis is mine.)

> A collection of properties that represent the presence of different browser features or bugs. **Intended for jQuery's internal use**; specific properties may be removed when they are no longer needed internally to improve page startup performance. **For your own project's feature-detection needs, we strongly recommend the use of an external library such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)** instead of dependency on properties in `jQuery.support`.

The previous documentation for `jQuery.support` reported the following properties and values.

- `$.support.boxmodel` is `false` in IE 6, and 7.
- `$.support.cssFloat` is `false` for IE 6, 7 and 8; it is `true` in IE 9.
- `$.support.leadingWhitespace` is `false` for IE 6, 7, and 8.
- `$.support.objectAll` is currently `false` for IE 6, 7, and 8.

Comment: Just for all others that find this comment, $.support.cssFloat is false for IE 6, 7 and 8. In IE 9 it is true.

Comment: I know this answer is kind of old, but debugging in IE9 with Browser Mode IE7 has $.support.boxModel === true. Maybe it's because I'm using a browser mode in IE9??

Answer (score 6):

hot from the documentation: We recommend against using this property, please try to use feature detection instead (see [jQuery.support](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.support)).

Answer (score 1):

Show the browser Information

```
jQuery.each( jQuery.browser, function( i, val ) {
$( "<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>" )
.appendTo( document.body );
});
```

Alert the version of IE's rendering engine that is being used. Will not work in jQuery 1.9 or later unless the jQuery Migrate plugin is included.

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
alert( $.browser.version );
}
```