# Internet Explorer 10 not redirecting

Tags: javascript

With Internet Explorer 10 removing the browser detection through markup, I need a new way to redirect users using Internet Explorer to a new page

I decided to use

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
   {

    self.location = "http://<url>"

   }
</script>
```

, but nothing is happening.
I am sure that there is something little missing that I am not seeing right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202305/how-do-i-detect-ie-8-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
window.location.href = "http://<url>";
```

And as Vucko suggested, [here is a way to detect IE using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202305/how-do-i-detect-ie-8-with-jquery).

And [here is how Microsoft suggests you check for IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).