# disable jquery for ie AND iphone/ipad

Tags: jquery, syntax, parallax

OK, so we were so excited to use a parallax effect on the front page of a new site. Cool right? WRONG. Mouse jitter scroll on ie & BG position is messed up on ie8 and under, ipad/iphone!!! Gotta love it.

So... I disabled ipad/iphone by using if else statement and need to add ie. 8 and under.

Can I just put it in like this???

if( (/iPhone|iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) | (/MSIE (\d+.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) ) {}
  else {parallax script}

I ask because there is no way for me to check... I have a MAC and Saucelabs doesn't really help in this situation.

I am using jQuery v1.11.0

Comment: maybe this will give a clue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202305/how-do-i-detect-ie-8-with-jquery

Comment: through more research i have found that this code is no longer valid :( ugh. Looking into modernizer and seeing if i can somehow utilize it to disable for ie mouse scrolling.