# Exclude mmenu in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, mmenu

As mmenu does not support IE8, I'd like to stop it from doing anything in it. That way I can apply a different menu for IE8 only.

How would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for this..

I wrapped it in the following code.

```
if ((document.documentMode || 100) > 8) {....};
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202545/2440296