# JQuery if browser = ie, creating warning box

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, browser, warnings, detect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting IE using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944169/detecting-ie-using-jquery)

Hello,

I'm trying to figure out how to detect the browser type on page load, and then, if the browser is internet explorer, create a warning box telling that user that it will be necessary for them to allow scripts for my galleries to work.

I know I need to use $jquery.support to accomplish this, but I do not know the syntax, or how to make it do it only once when the page finishes loading.  Is there a way I can create a cookie for the page saying that they've received the warning so that they won't get the warning every time they go to my main page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think any IE user needs to allow scripts? What if there is a user running Firefox with javascript disabled?

Comment: Um... You want to use JavaScript to tell your users they need to activate JavaScript?

Comment: @Pekka: I believe they could use JavaScript to *hide* the message telling them they should turn it on. :)

Comment: Using a client-side script to detect if client-side scripts are enabled is bound for failure.

Comment: ... yeah... hadn't thought of that....  egh....  Any thoughts as to how I could accomplish this, short of a persistent warning on the frontpage...

Comment: As @Groo mentions, create a static message and hide it if scripts _are_ enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to detect if JavaScript is enabled:

Check out the [noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_noscript.asp) tag. You can use it to add HTML which will be shown to users with JavaScript disabled. Alternatively, you can create a `div` containing a warning message, and then *hide* it using jQuery on page load:

```
<div class="noScriptWarning">Scripts are disabled!</div>
<script>
    // no, wait, they are enabled after all
    $(".noScriptWarning").hide();
</script>
```

Also, if JavaScript is disabled, you won't be able to access client-side cookies, but there are server-side solutions to transferring state (at least during a session).

Answer (score 8):

It's simple!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if ($.browser.msie) {
     // create the error box here
   }
});
```

Comment: ok, probably a stupid question, but to check if it's not ie I would use:
"if(!$.browser.msie){ }"  right?

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, jQuery has other variables that check for any type of browser, also.

Comment: I'm using this (link at end), but it's not hiding the box in firefox or chrome  --   http://jsfiddle.net/VHJdR/

Comment: This answer uses a deprecated feature (as of jQuery 1.3) and will not work in the latest version.

Comment: This is no longer a valid answer (for current versions of jQuery)

Answer (score 6):

The HTML5BoilerPlate project ( http://html5boilerplate.com/ ) employs a great method for handling browser-specific tweaks.  Basically, the html tag will have a CSS class called ie6/ie7/ie8, etc.  You can use CSS selectors to do custom overrides for IE.

Example:

```
<div class="ie_warning">Oh No, it is IE!</div>
<style>
  div.ie_warning { display:none; }
  .ie5 div.ie_warning, .ie7 div.ie_warning, .ie8 div.ie_warning { display:block !important; }
</style>
```

This works without javascript and it doesn't require jQuery or any other javascript library.

Comment: Cool.  That will probably work.  Any idea how to add a cookie so it only shows up once per browsing session?