# Most fast way to check for IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I want to check for IE and ask user to change brouser.
I tried:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<p>rrff</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
alertify.alert("Please change your brouser");
</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
alertify.alert("Message");
</script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
alertify.alert("Message");
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

(took it from Microsoft - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx)
But it show no result, except of termination of IE in two cases :)

How to check for IE and all related brousers to it? Too many functions fail here....

Comment: use uncle google there is HUGE amount of information about that.

Comment: something wrong with your code if `too many functions fail`...use feature detection

Comment: What @SzymonDziewoński says. Also, the article itself states `Note  As of December 2011, this topic has been archived and is no longer actively maintained.` which explains why it may have issues with more recent browsers

Comment: Do you calling `alertify` script before this? Did you try just `<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">alert("Please change your browser");</script><![endif]-->`

Comment: This is  good idea, but it do not work. (I mean <!--[if IE]>)

Comment: There are `ScriptEngine` functions in all IE versions. Please see more details on [this SO answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'll be good friend and tell you something about IE

**1. Plugin**

If you want just change some elements with changing class here's plugin 
http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/ which is great.

How it is work , for example add before element in css class like .ie8 #something and it will work in IE8 ONLY

**NOTE:** dont forget use jQuery library

**2. jQuery**

[Detecting IE using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944169/detecting-ie-using-jquery)
There is so many links, type in google "IE detection jquery" or something like that

**HINT:** before 1.9 jQuery detection was different but later 1.10 when use jQuery migrate you can still use those commands

**3. CSS**

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

I think thats all in 5 min , and when you spent some time you will learn all about that problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so whatever you are using is called Conditional Comment and this works fine.
if you just want to check for IE for any version, you can do it like:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alertify.alert("Please change your browser");
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

and if want to check for some particular version, then you can do it like:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<![endif]-->
```

and apart of it, you can check it in JavaScript itself, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    alertify.alert("Please change your browser");
}
</script>
```

But use any one of them, not all. Good luck!!

Comment: Can you, please, check if this code work for you? None of line above worked.  I have IE 11.

Comment: conditional comments are no longer supported

Comment: That's right, conditional comments are not being supported anymore in IE10+. So, you should then do it in JavaScript way...

Answer (score 0):

You should not browser sniff. Instead do feature detection like the following:

```
        <script>

    if (!('querySelector' in document)  //this should work in ie 9+
         || !('localStorage' in window)  //ie 8+
         || !('addEventListener' in window)  //ie 8 + (I think)
        || !('matchMedia' in window)) {//ie 10+

        //do something here
    }

</script>
```