# Ban Internet Explorer IE script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I know some sites like www.me.com bans IE6. It works when the page detects IE6 browser, it would trigger a DIV to let the user know the first time he accesses the website. Then the user closes, that notice won't appear again (at least for that session recorded in the cookie).

Where can I get such script?

Comment: IE 6 is more than capable of displaying web pages. By all means don't implement all your scripting in IE 6 but do you really need to exclude IE 6 users completely?

Comment: It's more like giving the visitors a warning that IE6 they are using may not work properly with all the scripts and CSS we usually display on our site. It will likely to break things, so it's better to include a warning about it, rather than having them think our website sucks in coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a script to do so:

[IE6 No More](http://www.ie6nomore.com/)

It works well, but it displays everytime a new page is presented. No cookie track whatsoever. I am still looking for one that display only once.

Answer (score 2):

[IE 6 Blocker Script](http://css-tricks.com/ie-6-blocker-script/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See this answer for [identifying browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566303/detect-internet-explorer-6-or-below-in-jquery), everything else is just jquery to add a div to the DOM and allow functionality for the user to close that.  You could then write to the cookie to say warning has been shown.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this to add to my web sites.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://aquawicket.com/noie.js"></script> 
<script> noie(); </script>
```